# Drupal 7 Intranet Portal (Open Atrium Alternative)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, portal, intranet

I need to create an intranet portal in Drupal 7.
What will the required contributed Drupal 7 modules to accomplish a complete Intranet Portal.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question will be different in each individual instance and will depend on the needs of the users.

Research the needs by speaking to the intended users, but don't ask them what they want. Instead, ask them about the problems they have. Ask which tasks they have trouble completing and find out the underlying cause. This will give you an idea of the applications they need.

Start with up to six of these problems and plan a schedule of work for the coming year with, say, quarterly releases. Develop a prototype and test it with your users. Listen to their feedback and continue to make improvements.

Don't think of this as a technology implementation, but as an ongoing process. You will find this helps with your stakeholder management: setting the six focus areas sets their expectations and listening to their feedback includes them in the process. This is valuable for adoption as you will spend less effort getting people onside since you already have advocates in place in the business.